# Keyword association learning algorithm

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-mining, prediction, reinforcement-learning

To model my problem, I'll use a dating site as an example (although this is not the actual case). My problem is I have a set of keywords that a user can input that they like. Say "Tall, dark hair, blue eyes", etc. and I want to map them to other users that fit that criteria. More than that however, I need to be able to learn from data I get back to make better predictions that are not-so-exact matches.

For example, if other users that are looking for people with 'dark hair' like users with 'black hair', or have a height of 6'4 but don't mention they are tall. I want to be able to make an association between those similar keywords and be able to also suggest those as well so it best returns what the user wants, even if it wasn't exactly what they asked for.

My question is what algorithm/approach is best suited for this? I've been looking into areas like:

- decision trees, but those seem to break down when no keywords match.
- naive bayes, which seem a bit more tolerant to missing connections, but require some prior knowledge about the connections, and since keywords can be anything, this seems like a road bloack
- ANN, but these don't seem to do well with text input
- KNN, but I'm not sure how to handle the possibly infinite user classifications?
- Some sort of A* map search, where each time a user1 likes a user2, I make a map connection between user1's likes and user2's traits, if that connection already exists, I just shorten it, then find the closest N users. I'm just not sure how scalable this is.

Any input is appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: It looks like a use case for [fuzzy logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a rather classic application of [association rule learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning): basically, if people looking for partners with 'dark hair' like a lot of 'black hair' accounts, then you have an association rule between the two. There are algorithms that can detect this.

As for your suggestions, have you tried an ANN? ANNs don't work at all with text input, but for most machine learning + text tasks, you turn the text into numeric data (see the bag of words model, for example). Once you have your numeric features, they shouldn't do too badly.

For example, you'd want your network trained to return adequate recommendations based on profile settings, right? You would feed it the profile settings, and if you have training data that shows users looking for people with 'dark hair' liking users with 'black hair', the ANN should learn that relationship.

Association rules sound like the way to go though.

Comment: Upvote, SVMs may be worth a mention too using a similar approach to that described for ANNs.